# JQuery validation not working after form reset

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm having an issue after I reset my form using:

```
$(".cancel").click(function () {
        validator.resetForm();
        $(':input', '#MyForm')
            .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
            .val('')
            .removeAttr('checked')
            .removeAttr('selected');
        //OR
        document.getElementById('MyForm').reset();
});
```

When I hit save again, the required fields are no longer required and the form posts back. How can I get the form to re-validate even after a reset?

This is a simple example since I'm just resetting validation and the form, but on other pages I have to manually manipulate certain fields, so I need this way of resetting forms to work.

This is an MVC created form if that makes any difference

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** After some trial and error, it seems that the problem shouldn't lie with the direct resetForm code but rather something else.

In the console I get the following javascript error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid label
```

and a warning

```
Use of attributes' specified attribute is deprecated. It always returns true.
```

Not sure if they're related to my issue but not sure what else to do at this point.

As far as the scripts I'm using:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js")
@*@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")*@
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-validate-messages.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.jeditable.mini.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.editable.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/extras/TableTools/media/js/TableTools.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Countdown.js")
@Styles.Render("~/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

1.9.1 was commented out because it was breaking on the first JQuery call. Is this related?

Comment: Do you have any `$.ajax` calls running on this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to force it to re-validate on submit:

```
$(".cancel").click(function () {
        $('#FormId')[0].reset();
        validator.resetForm();
    });

    $("#submitForm").click(function () {
        if ($("#FormId").valid()) {
            $("#FormId").submit();
        }
    });
```

Now I'm no longer relying on the submit feature of the form to trigger validation, but rather I'm triggering it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set validation again by using:

```
$j.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#MyForm');
```

**EDIT**

Can you try resetting form with a reset button, place this inside your form:

```
<button class="reset-button" type="reset">Reset form</button>
```

and disable your event handler on `.cancel`. Or change it to:

```
$('.cancel').click(function () {
    $('.reset-button').click();
});
```

and hide reset button if you don't want to show it.

Comment: I tried this but, now it's not validating the form at all. I tried including the jquery.unobtrusive before and after jquery.validate, but the validation is no longer there. I'm going to keep tinkering, but just wanted to get this in before you forget about me =)

Comment: Just tried the hidden reset button. It's working because its resetting the form, but after the reset it's still allowing a submit.

Comment: Got a syntax error on something that I think is non related. It's for jquery-min.js? Says invalid label? Odd because it's worked fine up till this point

{"version":3,"file":"jquery-1.9.1.min.js","sources":["jquery-1.9.1.js"],"names":["window","undefined"...

Comment: I did just get a deprecated warning, I may be including more than one JQuery .js file. Let me look into this

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's not related, if there's a javascript error somewhere it stops other javascript working.

Comment: Yeah pretty sure it's not that. I have an alert just after the reset just to make sure that it's not killing everything.

I'm still having trouble getting the unobtrusive one to work. Do you think that's the line of research I should head toward?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you reset the form in that way but work fine just with reset.
Jquery has a native reset

```
    $(".cancel").click(function () {
        $('#FormId')[0].reset();
     });
```

and the validation keep work smooth

Comment: Tried it that way, still no luck. Form still allowed to submit after reset

Comment: Form still allowed to submit??? but you should use .valid() before submit the form
`if ($('#FormId').valid()) {
    //do submit...
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var validator = $("#FormId").validate();

$(".cancel").click(function () {
    $('#FormId')[0].reset();
    validator.resetForm();
});
```

Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vm4a/1/)

Comment: Just tried that, still can submit after cancel... had a real hope for that one =P

Comment: submitting after cancel works for me in the fiddle. It doesn't work for you? @DeiasR

Comment: Nope, cancel still allows a resubmit. It's a strange problem, and I'm not really sure whats causing it.

Comment: My fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7vm4a/1/ I do the following: 1) fill the form keeping one required field empty 2) press submit > does not submit - validator errors 3) press cancel > resets the form 4) press submit > does not submit - validator errors. Is this the same steps you are trying out? or are your steps different? @DeiasR

Comment: Yup, thats exactly what I do. I have 2 required fields, hit submit, cant submit, hit cancel, resets form, hit submit, exception thrown

Comment: I take it that this happens with your form, not the fiddle I created. What is the exception thrown? can you add it here? @DeiasR

Comment: Sorry I guess I should have been clearer about that. The exception that is thrown is because I'm not doing any server-side validation, so the exception is the server trying to parse an empty text box as a date.

Comment: @DeiasR then the problem lies not with the validation and reset codes but elsewhere. It would be helpful if you edit your question and post any errors/warnings that you find in your console.