# jQuery Lost validation rules after form reset

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have a form that contains dozen of fields. based on codes from Stackoverflow I decided and experienced that the best way to reset form (back to old values before mistake edit) is: **$("#Form1")[0].reset();**

But problem is then that validated form fields lost their validation rules: if I try after that to enter wrong contents validation isn't working! I wish to know some methode where is possible to reset form and put validation into initial state like it was when form is loaded. Is it possible? Thanks.

```
    <script>   
       $(document).ready(function()
       {
          $("#Form1").submit(function(event)
          {
             var isValid = $.validate.form(this);
             return isValid;
          });
          $("#txtInvbr").validate(
          {
             required: true,
             type: 'number',
             rules...,
             error_text: 'Only zero and numbers'
          });
      });
      </script>
```

Comment: Please add all the pertinent code to reproduce the issue. We can’t guess an answer if that’s what you wish for :-)

Comment: This might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363619/jquery-validation-not-working-after-form-reset

Comment: Hello @Terry: I saw suggested example but dosn't help; what is validator there? Tried to implement code but no help. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I found is this:

```
$("#Form1")[0].reset(); //reset form at first
       if ( jQuery.fn.trigger ) {
          jQuery( document ).trigger( "ready" ).unbind( "ready" );
       }
```

in cancel function, and it works.